# Java Spring - GET Request with two parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http, get

I want to make a `GET` request to my server that receives two parameters, `uniqueConfig` and `commitHash`. The code for this operation in my `Controller` class is as follows:

```java
@GetMapping("/statsUnique")
public ResponseEntity<Object> hasEntry(@RequestParam("uniqueConfig") String uniqueConfig,
                                       @RequestParam("commitHash") String commitHash) {
    Optional<Stats> statsOptional = 
        codecService.findByUniqueConfigAndCommitHash(uniqueConfig, commitHash);
    if (statsOptional.isPresent()) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(true);
    }
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(false);
}
```

The issue is, when I try to make the `GET` request using Postman, the server returns a `400 - Bad Request` with the following error message:

> MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required request parameter 'uniqueConfig' for method parameter type String is not present]

my `JSON` on Postman looks like this:

```json
{
    "commitHash": "ec44ee022959410f9596175b9424d9fe1ece9bc8",
    "uniqueConfig": "bowing_22qp_30fr_29.97fps_fast-preset"
}
```

Please note that those aren't the only attributes and I've tried making the same request with all of them on the `JSON`. Nonetheless, I receive the same error.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `GET` request doesn't (or at least shouldn't) have a body. Parameters defined by the `@RequestParam` annotations should be sent in the query string, not a JSON body, i.e., the request should be something like

```
http://myhost/statsUnique?commitHash=commitHash&uniqueConfig=bowing_22qp_30fr_29.97fps_fast-preset
```